# How can I convert % to # in dynamic URL via htacesss

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hash, url-rewriting

Our site's links are like this:

```
https://www.example.com/video.html#11
```

But I don't know why, sometimes some sites convert our hash like this:

```
https://www.example.com/video.html%11
```

So I tried this line, it works but links are dynamic-based, because the ID of the video may change so I need to modify it.

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/video.html#11
```

And also, I have the following line in the `.htaccess` file but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: You can only specify one ErrorDocument, so this won't work for multiple different IDs. You should implement a RewriteRule instead, that externally redirects these to the correct form. `%11` would be a "vertical tab" character, but RewriteRule matches against the already URL-decoded path - so I don't know if you can match that directly (spaces can be escaped with a backslash, but I don't know if that will work for the vertical tab character as well), you might have to use a RewriteCond that checks the original request instead (similar to https://serverfault.com/q/122879)

Comment: What range of IDs are you expecting?

Comment: "I have the following line in the `.htaccess` file but it doesn't work" - This is unrelated to the current issue and should be asked as a different question. There's nothing particularly wrong with that rule so you may have a conflict with other directives or it's simply not doing what you think it's doing. (What are _you_ expecting that rule to be doing?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> https://www.example.com/video.html%11
> ```

You can redirect this (and similar) URLs to replace `%` with `#` using something like the following mod_rewrite rule at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(/video\.html)%(\d+)\s
RewriteRule . %1#%2 [NE,R=302,L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` contains the first line of the request headers, is not %-decoded and is not affected by other rewrites.

The `%1` and `%2` backreferences in the *substitution* string contain `/video.html` and the number after the `%` sign respectively.

The `NE` (`noescape`) flag is required to prevent the `#` sign being URL-encoded (as `%23`) in the response and being interpreted as part of the URL-path.

HOWEVER, there are further complications with this as it depends on what ID numbers you are expecting after `%`. `%NN` (the first 2 digits) are obviously seen as a %-encoded character in the URL. The *browser* will convert *some* of these %-encoded characters back into the literal character before making the request, so `%NN` may not reach your server. Notably, this affects the standard latin characters `%61`(a) to `%86`(z), numbers, uppercase letters, etc.

For example, given a request for `/video.html%61`, the *browser* will likely convert this to `/video.htmla` before making the request. In `.htaccess` these will need to be checked for and converted manually, unless you have access to the server config to create a `RewriteMap` for looking up the equivalent hex-codes. (The built-in `escape()` function only %-encodes *special characters* - like the browser - so it will have no effect here.)

*Aside:* An additional complication on *Windows* servers is that any %-encoded [characters that are not permitted in Windows filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names) (eg. codes 0-31, which notably includes `%11` (vertical tab) from your example) will result in a 403 Forbidden response before `.htaccess` is able to process the request. To resolve this you would need to move this directive to the main server config (or VirtualHost) in order to process the request *before* it is mapped to the filesystem.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer, I appreciate it. But now I have another problem: It's working when I type #21, #11, or similar, but if I type #31, #59, or #3, it gives a bad 400 request and does not convert. I tried that add %3%4... to the related line but nothing has changed.

Comment: @folec94 "when I type #21, #11" - Presumably you mean when you type `%21`, `%11`? If you are getting a "400 Bad Request" response then this is likely triggered by other "security" rules defined in your server config - which occurs _before_ `.htaccess` is able to process the request. You can sometimes workaround this by moving the directives from `.htaccess` to the main server config, which is processed much earlier.

Comment: @folec94 Another complication (which I mentioned above) is that `%31` and `%59` map to literal characters `1` and `Y` respectively. Some browsers (notably Google Chrome) will decode these %-encoded characters before making the request. So your server actually receives `/video.html1` and `/video.htmlY` instead of `/video.html%31` and `/video.html%59` respectively.

Comment: @folec94 "I tried that add %3%4... to the related line" - I'm not sure what you mean by this?